# Error when including header with array declaration

Tags: c

I have a header file and two source files. In said header file I have the following declaration:

```
const char *letters[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
```

I have included my header file in both source files. When I try to compile I get:

```
/tmp/cc6gLw9s.o:(.data+0xa0): multiple definition of `letters'
/tmp/ccjqd0rr.o:(.data+0xa0): first defined here
```

Comment: You have the same variable defined multiple times, it's an array but still a variable. You shouldn't put variable **definitions** in headers.

Comment: That is technically not a *compiler* error but a *linker* error, and means that you *define* the variable in multiple [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) (basically source file with all included headers). Don't *define* variables (or functions) in header files.

Answer (score 5):

If you compile the 2 source files separately and each of them includes the header, then the variable `letters` will be declared twice, once in each source file. To prevent this, declare the variable as `extern` in the header file.

```
extern const char *letters[];
```

Then, put the actual variable in **1** source file.

```
const char *letters[] = {...};
```

Comment: Can you please add a sentence or two about why global variables, especially those with external linkage, are problematic? It's the only thing that bothers me about this answer.

Comment: I'm not really sure what to say about that. I get that they're ugly, but I haven't really had any experience with them being particular trouble in the past since I primarily use unity builds.

Comment: It's not so much about the build as much as it is about good design for encapsulation. It also becomes a nightmare in multi-threaded programs. But okay, NVM.

Answer (score 1):

Including a file in C is almost literally copying and pasting it. If a header is included twice in the same compilation it will be as if that code was written twice.

This is usually avoided by using the pre-processor to prevent the header from being compiled twice.

```
#ifndef _MYHEADERS_H_
#define _MYHEADERS_H_

const char *letters[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};

#endif
```

This is in addition to the issues brought up in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@Schwern's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42702812/6850771), you can also do this:

```
#pragma once

const char *letters[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
```

Note that `#pragma once` isn't standard C, but it is [supported on most compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability).